# Parsing an Input value using Split

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" id="personName" />
```

Given possible values like:

- James
- James Bond
- James Van Bond
- James Van Bond the Very First

I want to learn how to split the value by space, and then obtain the first value as FirstName and all the remaining values as Last name.

Possible? Is split the way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/EpbVc/

```
var value = $('#personName').val().split(' ');

var firstName = value.shift();

var restOfNames = value.join(' ');
```

Uses [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split on a single space. If there could be multiple spaces, you could use `.split(/\s+/)`.

Then it uses [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first item from the Array, and assign it to `firstName`.

Finally it uses [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the rest of the Array into a string using a single space as the separator.

Comment: @AnApprentice. The `.split()` will [still work](http://jsfiddle.net/EpbVc/1/) with a single word. You're getting `undefined` back as the value, so there may be a problem with your selection. Is the DOM ready?

Comment: You could first get the `.val()`, then test to see if you received any input before continuing. `var value = $('#personName').val(); if( value ) { /*do the rest*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

use .split(" ") to split into array and then use .join(" ")